# How to make a queue (FIFO) in JS using arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am working a question on FreeCodeCamp. I need to add a number to the end of the array, then remove the first element of the array. The function called nextInLine should return the element that was removed from it.

I'm not completely new, but I'm not advanced in JS either. However, I'm new to algorithms. I've watched Youtube videos for assistance with Queues. I have this concept fairly understood as follows:

```
//array as queue (FIFO)
const arr = [];
arr.push(5); // [5]
arr.push(7); // [5,7]
arr.push(9); // [5,7,9]
console.log(arr.shift()); // [7,9]
console.log(arr.shift()); // [9]
console.log(arr.shift()); // []
```

However, when trying to implement this idea into my code, I seem to not maybe fully understand the presented problem in order to make it run. I am to modify the function nextInLine, and the comment that says //Display Code, I am to change that line as well.

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Your code here
  arr.push(arr[0]);
  arr.shift();
  return console.log(arr, item);  // Change this line
}

// Test Setup
var testArr = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Display Code
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr)); // Modify this line to test
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

When running the code, this is what is showing for me.

```
nextInLine([], 5) should return a number.
nextInLine([], 1) should return 1
nextInLine([2], 1) should return 2
nextInLine([5,6,7,8,9], 1) should return 5
After nextInLine(testArr, 10), testArr[4] should be 10
```

My function is outputting /* 2,3,4,5,1 */ but it seems to be incorrect. Perhaps I am failing to put it into an array? I have the first number (1) at the beginning, but am I failing to simply put my answer in an array? Or am I not even producing the right numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `shift` first and then `push`.

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  var removedElement = arr.shift();
  arr.push(item);
  return removedElement;
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see, you're creating a variable named 'removeElement' and assigning it the literal 'removed element', and you're also returning that. As well as pushing whatever 'item' you decide to push to the end. I seem to understand what I was missing, which was assign the shift method to a variable, then returning said variable. Thank you for the input @Samuel

Answer (score 1):

You should be pushing `item` onto the array. You're simply moving the first element of the array to the end, without adding the new element.

And `console.log()` prints its arguments, it doesn't return them. So your function is just returning `undefined`.

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item); // add new item to end
  return arr.length > 1 ? arr.shift() : null; // remove first item and return it
}
```

The conditional in the `return` statement prevents it from shifting off the new element if it's the only thing in the array, i.e. the array was originally empty.

Comment: Oh right! I completely forgot that console.log(); does not return anything and comes out as undefined. It will log the results but does not return it back to the function? If I said that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.splice` to remove the first element from an array.

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  var firstElement = arr[0];
  arr.splice(0, 1);
  arr.push(item);
  return firstElement;
}

var arr = [];
console.log('nextInLine(arr, 5) should return undefined and arr should be [5]:');
console.log('return value:', nextInLine(arr, 5));
console.log('array:', arr);
console.log('--------------------------------------')

console.log('nextInLine(arr, 1) should return 5 and arr should be [1]:');
console.log('return value:', nextInLine(arr, 1));
console.log('array:', arr);
console.log('--------------------------------------')

arr = [5,6,7,8,9];
console.log('nextInLine(arr, 10) should return 5 and arr should be [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:');
console.log('return value:', nextInLine(arr, 10));
console.log('array:', arr);
console.log('--------------------------------------')
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the input @pindev. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

Update: With the help of everyone, I was not only able to solve, but understand WHY the solution was, what it was! I just had to switch around the following lines of code and that did it. Apparently they wanted you to push the item first, THEN shift on the array. Who would've knew LOL. Thanks everyone! I don't know how to close a forum post down, so I will leave it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this also

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
       arr.push(item);
       return arr.shift();
    }
    
    
 var arr = [1,5,6]
 console.log("removed element is : ", nextInLine(arr,10))
 console.log("array is  : ", arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

i did fifo function with two array method - 
[concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
const nextInLine = (arr, item) => item ? arr.concat(item).slice(1) : arr;
```